# collation issue between two servers that have different collation set

Tags: sql-server, collation, linked-server

I have encountered a collation issue while performing select query via linked server. Query returns rows but there are some problems in characters (E.g Turkish İ becomes I , Turkish Ğ becomes G)

**Server Collation:** Latin1_General_CI_AS  (SQL Server 2012 11.0.3000)

**Linked Server Collation :** TURKISH_CI_AS (SQL Server 2000 (8.0.2040)

There is no collation changing in query. Query is simply **a select * from Table** statement. I also tried to specify Collation in the columns but it did not work either. (**e.g** : **select ColumnName TURKISH_CI_AS from Table**)

I already set **Collation Compatible** property to True and **CollationName** to TURKISH_CI_AS however it does not work.

Another thing is that i have another database server whose server collation is also Latin1_General_CI_AS(SQL Server 2012 11.0.3000) and linked server from here to TURKISH_CI_AS database works fine.

Only difference between source servers is that working one's edition is SQL Server Enterprise and failing one's is SQL Server Business Inteligence.

What could be the issue?

Comment: does the query work on the linked server ? Is the table actually a view ?

Comment: Where do you see ther result? Management Studio or application? Have you tried `SELECT CONVERT(NVarChar(100), ColumName)`? What does `Set ... CollationName to ...` mean? Collation is a property of a column not a database

Comment: sorry for late response @adrianm, after posting question i realized that problematic  column's type is char(20). i casted it to nvarchar(20) and it worked.